# Should we be allowing offensive terms in peoples' profiles?

Tags: discussion

I came across a question and viewed the author's [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3705008/user3705008).

The use of that image (well in this case I think it's the words in the image) bothers me.

I'm completely at home with the idea that something that offensive is a personal thing, and while I use those words rather liberally on other informal social media, they bother me in the context of this this and other Stack Exchange sites.

I can't put my finger on it, but I feel that being the primary source of programming help on the web we should be discouraging this kind of behaviour.

Comment: [Offensive profiles - where to draw the line?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208551) and somewhat related - [What, if anything should one do if a user's "about me" profile section contains extremely inflammatory terms (racist, etc.)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52730)

Comment: i flagged a question once noting profantity in the avatar (the same word) and the flag was declined (no evidence ...) so it must be ok.  I think another mod might have seen it or another flag because the avatar was changed shortly thereafter

Comment: @Plutonix: You seem to have contradicted yourself.  See my answer below.

Comment: There is a whole chatroom dedicated to PHP, how offensive it that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's already been fixed, but for posterity, here's the image in question:

[image]

Now then.   While I found the image somewhat humorous, this is a professional website, and the Gravatar image is considered a public artifact.  So these kinds of images are not acceptable as identicons.

Such an image would, of course, be perfectly acceptable in the "about me" portion of the user's profile.  There, it just makes the user look like an ass, not the entire site.

Comment: Yes I do agree that the public one is not acceptable. I suppose this is a fine compromise.